# Parallel.For that fails if the loopcount is 1

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have the following code; it executes on a large loop count although the results are not consistent with the non-parallel version, but it fails if the loopcount is 1. What is wrong with my Parallel.For?

I am calculating correlation coefficients of ~1000 stocks against ~500 indexes; each has ~250 measurements over time. Every stock (target) is correlated against every index (test). The target loop is serial and I want to do the test loop in parallel since, for each test, the target data is the same.

The correlation is calculated for one test on this one target in method DoOneTest, calling it with the two indexes and a target data array representing the target data that is to be constant for all tests.

```
teststart = 0;
UserUnique.TestRank = 1; //# of tests
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 };
Parallel.For(teststart, UserUnique.TestRank - 1, options, paralleltestcounter =>
{
      int testindex = paralleltestcounter;
      UserUnique.outputGrid = DoOneTest(tgtindx, testindex, x);
 });
```

Comment: Setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1 would seem to defeat the purpose of using `Parallel.For` in the first place.

Comment: I notice you have a history of not accepting answers that help you, to do this navigate to the helpful answer, and click on the tick underneath the posts score and up/down vote buttons. The tick will turn green to let you know it worked. At this area you can also provide up/down votes on the answer. This helps other people know if this information was helpful to or not.

Comment: Thanks for telling me how to respond! Thanks too for the answer; I had assumed that it would do one loop as in the sequential case.

Comment: @petergregory In the sequential case `for (int i = 0; i < 0; ++i)` the loop will never enter as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails because the loop count is set to 1 and then has 1 subtracted from it:

```
UserUnique.TestRank = 1; //# of tests
Parallel.For(teststart, UserUnique.TestRank - 1, options, paralleltestcounter =>
```

Therefore your `fromInclusive` and `toExclusive` are both `0` so the loop never enters. Change your loop to:

```
Parallel.For(teststart, UserUnique.TestRank, options, paralleltestcounter =>
```

For more information [see MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781401(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Also as @juharr comments:

> Setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1 would seem to defeat the purpose of using Parallel.For in the first place.

Comment: juharr, a simple way to test a  parallel code is to see if it gives the same result as the serial version when you turn parallelism off. It didn't.